# Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']

Tags: python, html, django

I am working on a Small Django Blog project but got stuck with this error:-

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']
Exception Location: /home/manish/Videos/open-source/Blog-Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 677
Python Executable:  /home/manish/Videos/open-source/Blog-Env/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.2
Python Path:    
['/home/manish/Videos/open-source/Blogger/mysite',
 '/usr/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/manish/Videos/open-source/Blog-Env/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 22 Aug 2020 14:40:46 +0530
```

Here's the Django codes:-`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import (
        PostDetailView,
        PostUpdateView,
        PostDeleteView,
        PostListView,
        about,
        post_create,
        Profileview
    )

urlpatterns = [
    path("", PostListView.as_view(), name="blog-home"),
    path("about/", about, name="blog-about"),
    path("profileview/<name>", Profileview, name="blog-profile"),
    path("post/<int:pk>/", PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post-detail"),
    path("post/<int:pk>/update/", PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="post-update"),
    path("post/<int:pk>/delete/", PostDeleteView.as_view(), name="post-delete"),
    path("post_create/", post_create, name="post_create"),
]
```

Here's the `views.py` file:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Post
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.views.generic import DetailView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import PostForm
from django.db.models import Q

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post


class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
............
............
```

Here's the `base.html` file:-

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}" type="text/css">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <header class="site-header">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="navbar-brand mr-4" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Django Blog</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Home</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/about">About</a>
              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'post_create' %}">Post Create</a>
              {% endif %}
              <!--Search Bar-->
              <div class="search-bar">
                <form method="GET" action="/" style="display:inline-block; line-height:24px; border-radius: 80px">
                  <input type="text" placeholder="&nbsp;Search Blogs..." onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = '&nbsp;Search Blogs...';}" name ="q" required="" size="29" style="border-radius: 80px">
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
            <div class="navbar-nav">

              {% if user.is_authenticated %}
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' %}">Profile</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
              {% else %}
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
              {% endif %}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>


    <main role="main" class="container">
      <!--Slider Start-->
      {% block slider%}

      {% endblock %}
      <!--Slider End-->
      <span style="display:inline-block; width: 3px;"></span>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {% if messages %}
                {% for messages in messages %}
                <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
                    {{ messages }}
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
          {% block content %}
          
          {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="content-section">
            <h3>Our Sidebar</h3>
            <p class='text-muted'>You can put any information here you'd like.
              <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Latest Posts</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Announcements</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">Calendars</li>
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">etc</li>
              </ul>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I think something has to be done with the urls.py or in some changes in the base.html file. Since the problem is arising in the root URL. I have tried doing changes here and there nothing seems to be fixing this issue.
here's the `home.html` file:-

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %} 

{% block slider%}
    <div class="slider">
        <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-0" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" style="display: none;" />
        <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-1" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" style="display: none;" />
        <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-2" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" style="display: none;" />
        <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-3" type="radio" class="input-slide input-slide-num" style="display: none;" />
        <input name="input-slider" id="input-slide-autoplay" type="radio" class="input-slide" checked style="display: none;" />
        <ul>
            <li class="slide-0"></li>
            <li class="slide-1"></li>
            <li class="slide-2"></li>
            <li class="slide-3"></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="slide-description">
            <label class="slide-0">
                <h1 class="text-slide">{{ mostliked1.title }}</h1>
                <h5>{{mostliked1.content|truncatechars:70}}</h5>
                <a href="{% url 'post-detail' mostliked1.id %}" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
            </label>
            <label class="slide-1">
                <h1 class="text-slide">{{ mostliked2.title }}</h1>
                <h5>{{mostliked2.content|truncatechars:70}}</h5>
                <a href="{% url 'post-detail' mostliked2.id %}" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
            </label>
            <label class="slide-2">
                <h1 class="text-slide">{{ mostliked3.title }}</h1>
                <h5>{{mostliked3.content|truncatechars:70}}</h5>
                <a href="{% url 'post-detail' mostliked3.id %}" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
            </label>
            <label class="slide-3">
                <h1 class="text-slide">{{ mostliked4.title }}</h1>
                <h5>{{mostliked4.content|truncatechars:70}}</h5>
                <a href="{% url 'post-detail' mostliked4.id %}" class="readmorebutton">Read More</a>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="slider-dot">
            <label class="slide-0" for="input-slide-0"></label>
            <label class="slide-1" for="input-slide-1"></label>
            <label class="slide-2" for="input-slide-2"></label>
            <label class="slide-3" for="input-slide-3"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %} 

{% block content %} 
    {% for post in posts %}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'blog-profile' name=post.author %}">{{ post.author }}</a>
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted }}</small>
                </div>
                <h2><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock%}
```

Comment: show us PostListView template

Comment: I have added @iklinac, See if you can find something.

Comment: it does seem like you didn't set mostliked ids "{% url 'post-detail' mostliked1.id %}", up to 4, you should try to comment out this part to see if it works also rest of PostListView would be beneficiary

Comment: The URL loaded by commenting out the line you suggested, but my slider is now blank. I need the slider to work, what can I do, is there any alternative.

Comment: as I said you dont set mostliked in PostListView which is source of problem, so you should that particular code to  PostListView

Comment: `{% url 'post-detail' post.id %}`  please change this to `{% url 'post-detail' pk=post.id %}`. Here we pass value then `argument_name = value`. Please change like this in all template.